# Procedure is not working on Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a simple "Hello World" procedure .... but it is not working

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings
AS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');
END;
/
```

After that I executed it like this :

```
EXECUTE greetings;
```

but I get an error :

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Images are here :

[image]

[image]

Please help out as soon as possible ...thanks :)

Comment: What happens if you try to run BEGIN GREETINGS; END; ?

Comment: thanks @micklesh if i run BEGIN GREETINGS; END;  this one is working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `EXECUTE` is a SQL*Plus statement. It's not a valid SQL statement.

The error message being returned   `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` makes it appear that the client you are using is not emulating the SQL*Plus EXEC statement.

The general form for executing a PL/SQL procedure is to execute an anonymous PL/SQL block.

```
   BEGIN greetings(); END;
   /
```